# How to rearrange this vector without a loop?

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have a vector `A = 1:2*N`. I want to rearrange its elements into another vector like this:

```
B = [A(1:2), A(N+1:N+2), A(3:4), A(N+3:N+4), ..., A(N-1:N), A(2*N-1:2*N)];
```

How can I implement this in Matlab most efficiently? without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work when `N` is even:

```
N = 4;
A = 1:2*N;

temp = permute(reshape(A,2,[],2), [1,3,2]);

B = temp(:)'
```

if `N` can be odd, I guess you could pad `A` with two `NaN`s and then remove the last two elements from `B` at the end? i.e. `A(end+1:end+2) = NaN` at the beginning and then `B = B(1:end-2)` at the end